# Late loading/delay loading of knockout template until click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

here is my HTML

This is a ko component. The page loads, and loads the component as you would expect. The visible: binding is set to false to begin with, and changes on a button click to show this modal. However, $root.configurator.thisRow() or...thisTab() has no value, and cannot have value until the button click event fires, where $root.configurator.storeRows(tab,row) is being called.

How do I delay loading this template until after ...thisRow() and ...thisTab() have values?  Note: cannot use jQuery

```
<div class="config-div">
<div class="my-table">

        <div data-bind="text: $root.configurator.thisRow().description.substring(0,5)"></div>
        <div data-bind="attr: {id: $root.configurator.thisTab().name.substring(0,4) +'-'+ $root.configurator.thisRow().description.substring(0,5)">
            <div data-bind="text: $root.configurator.initConfigSorted(thisTab(), thisRow())"></div>
            <!--ko foreach: {data: $root.configurator.config.blah, as: 'thing'}-->
            <div class="config-list">
                <div class="row single-row  list-group-item">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p data-bind="text: thing.name"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
   <button data-bind="click: function(){ $root.configurator.toggleConfig() }">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed value, e.g. something like:

```
this.templateReady = ko.computed(function() {
   return yourToggle() && thisRow() && thisTab();
})
```

Comment: thisRow() and thisTab() are on the ViewModel, so I can get them whenever I need them, but they are only assigned on click so I can get THIS tab and THIS row from a long table on multiple tabs with the same rows.

i.e. employee: name, phone, student: name, phone, person: name, phone.

So I don't need the function, or even to toggle. the toggle is simply a show/hide kind of thing. I need to delay loading that html, maybe an ajax to get it? is there any built in way to do that?

Comment: Yes the computed is part of view model too - so I'd recommend you define this "template ready" logic as a computed, vs thinking too "manually" such as using delays, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate some? I'm not following what you mean, and your code is too abstract for me at the moment to really follow what you're trying to say.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear- main point am making is don't think in terms of "I need to delay loading of template", as that's likely not the "Knockout way".   Your template visibility, and/or the text bindings should only show once the data is bound.  It looks like part of the issue is you are doing JS calls the data which will fail if data is null:  `thisRow().description.substring(0,5)`. If you start a jsfiddle with your code, I can demonstrate.